# What's the story between Bourne and Nicky?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bourne-ultimatum

At *The Bourne Ultimatum* (00:47), in a convenience store, Bourne ask Nicky

> Why are you helping me?

Nicky answers

> It was difficult for me...
>
> with you.
>
> You really don't remember anything.

Then 2 officers' intruding ends this conversation.

Obviously there's something unsaid. What happens between Bourne and Nicky (before *Treadstone*)?

Comment: Is it possible to include a link to this video clip at all?

Comment: @John Uh, I don't see a way.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the clip in question.

There is the allusion that Nicky and Jason were in a relationship before the events of The Bourne Identity.

Logistically it makes sense, because they were both stationed in Paris, and undoubtedly Jason would have had contact with Nicky, since she was his handler.

Comment: Is colleague romance possible ... for agents?

Comment: Everything they do is shrouded in secrecy, even their love.